# Geo coder returning wrong results

Tags: php, google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am using google geocoder API in php to get the lat and lang of a place.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Hollywood,+Newyork,+CA&sensor=true';
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    $lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; 
    $long = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    echo "latitude: " . $lat . " longitude: " . $long;exit;
?>
```

Its returning lattitude and longitude values as 34.1408919,-118.350441. But hollywood is in florida US. So it should not return any result for me. How i will achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The return is based on your query, in this case: `Hollywood, New York, CA`.
Google is returning the lat and long for `New York St, North Hollywood, CA 91602, USA`

Change your query if you are looking for a different address..